# How to enable a radiobutton list using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I enable a radiobutton list using jQuery in IE 8 when it's disabled on the server side.
The code works fine in Chrome, but does not work to get it enabled in IE 8.

```
$(this).removeAttr("disabled"); //code works in Chrome, but not in IE
```

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

Better using this:

```
$(this).attr('disabled', false);
```